# python pdf2image "May not be a PDF file" error

Tags: python, centos, pdf2image

On Centos 8 operating system, I get an error when converting pdf pages to jpg files with Python.

```
from pdf2image import convert_from_path
import sys

images = convert_from_path("test.pdf",500)
for i in range(len(images)):
    images[i].save('page'+ str(i) +'.jpg', 'JPEG')
```

As a result it gives this error. I can run the PDF file locally, but it doesn't work when I want to save it as a jpg.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pdf2image/pdf2image.py", line 479, in pdfinfo_from_path
    raise ValueError
ValueError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pdf_conv.py", line 7, in <module>
    images = convert_from_path(pdf_path,500)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pdf2image/pdf2image.py", line 98, in convert_from_path
    page_count = pdfinfo_from_path(pdf_path, userpw, poppler_path=poppler_path)["Pages"]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pdf2image/pdf2image.py", line 489, in pdfinfo_from_path
    "Unable to get page count.\n%s" % err.decode("utf8", "ignore")
pdf2image.exceptions.PDFPageCountError: Unable to get page count.
Syntax Warning: May not be a PDF file (continuing anyway)
Syntax Error: Couldn't find trailer dictionary
Syntax Error: Couldn't find trailer dictionary
Syntax Error: Couldn't read xref table
```

Answer (score 0):

PDF != PDF - there are different Versions of it. Mayhap your python `pdf2image` does not like/know the *kind* of PDF you feed it. Use AcrobatReader or something alike to check what you are trying to convert and see if `pdf2image` supports it.

See [Which ISO standards does pdf2image support](https://github.com/Belval/pdf2image/issues/210) (short:  [pdf2image supports all PDF standards that poppler supports.](https://github.com/Belval/pdf2image/issues/210#issuecomment-898160780))